# Skeletal Animation Mirrored

Tags: skeletal-animation, gpu, skinning

Okay so I've been working on GPU skinning skeletal animations.

I need help assessing what is going on here. Looks like the animations are completely mirrored

What are the possible issues? I've been looking at it for so long I'm numb to it. Maybe some fresh eyes will be able to pinpoint what it could be?

Thanks in advanced.

This is in Blender(how is should look):
[image: Proper animation]

This is what it looks like in my engine:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I had to negate the w component of the rotation quaternion on both the bind pose bones and the animation frame bones.